# Flutter Svg image dosen't load

Tags: flutter, dart, svg, mobile

When I run my code the svg does not appear.
I already added `flutter_svg: ^0.19.0` to the dependencies.

How can i solve this?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/svg.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        elevation: 0,
        leading: Builder(
          builder: (BuildContext context) {
            return IconButton(
              icon: SvgPicture.asset('assets/icons/home.svg'),
              onPressed: () { Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer(); },
               tooltip: MaterialLocalizations.of(context).openAppDrawerTooltip,
        ); 
      },    
    ),
  )
);
```

}
}

Comment: can you please add your svg file here ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the asset path is missing in `pubspec.yaml` file

Add

```
assets:
    - assets/icons/
```

**Edit**

and please check your svg file ... Flutter_svg only support special svg
format .you should Export your svg like this.

[image]

Comment: it should work if above things followed properly,try to kil app and run it again

Comment: What exactly are you exporting it from?

Answer (score 0):

if have svg have style tag then not support flutter svg

Comment: I have no idea what you want to say here. Can you add some code to illustrate? See also [answer].

Comment: open svg file code in notepad or notePad++ and see <style>  ... </style> . if this tag is mention then svg not display .

Answer (score 0):

**this is working fine for me please see format in picture hope fully help you**
[image]

Comment: Please explain briefly the content of the image. Not everyone will be able to see it.